# which eventlistener to register to know when view is added to window and drawn

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got a view that is added to Window by calling method:

```
mWindowManager.addView(mTheftLockedView, lp).
```

I have some functionality to be called when this added view is visible on screen. To make sure the view is visible  I tried registering to `onAttachedTowindow()` and `OnGlobalLayoutListener()` events. But these did not work for me. Can any one let me know which event listener should I register for ?

Comment: When you said OnGlobalLayoutListener did not work (I suppose with ViewTreeObserver). What happened there ?

Comment: OnGlobalLayoutListener got called before the view was visible on screen. My scenario is once the view is added, I have to inform other application to remove initialization screen. So when I used OnGlobalLayoutListener, I there was some gap between the initialization screen removed and my  view got visible.

Comment: Have you tried posting a message to UI thread, so that this message will be picked up once layouting is completely done.